# Windows 7: which version for which Pentium?

Tags: windows-7, intel-pentium, 32-vs-64-bit

I have to install Windows 7 on two machines, but I'm not sure if I must pick Windows 7 version 32 bits or 64 bits for each of them. Here's what appears in my computer > properties:

1. Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
2. Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz

Comment: Look, can you tell me the exact CPU model? You can have x86 and x64 Pentium 4 CPUs @3GHz models. If you have Intel P4 531 or 630 or 631 (all @3.00GHz) than you have x64 bit CPU. But I see no reason for having x64 OS on less than 4Gb of memory

Comment: Also, take a look @Journeyman Geek post and download free CPU-Z to check for exact CPU models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentium D is better of those two. It's a dual-core vs. Pentium 4 single core, so regardless of  what version of Intel pentium 4 you have (x64 or x86), it's faster. Pentium D Smithfield core (90nm) is actually 2x Pentium 4 Prescott cores, and Pentium D Presler core (65nm) is 2x Pentium 4 Cedar Mill cores

Anyway, I would suggest you to check the available memory as well. Minimum for Win 7 x86 is 1 GB, while for Win 7 x64 is 2 GB

If you don't have or you are not planning to use more than 3GB of RAM, I would strongly suggest you to go with the Windows x86, regardless of the CPU ability to work or not on x64 OS

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 3.5 gb of ram, go with 64 bit - its almost certainly a 64 bit system.

A more scientific way to find out is to look up if your processor supports EMT64T - you can look this up on intel's website or use a suitable tool to find out - on windows you can use cpu-z

[image]

This is a 64 bit system and has the EMT64T instruction (AMD systems may have a AMD64 instruction)

If these are systems with no os, boot a linux livecd and use `/proc/cpuinfo` - you're looking for the lm flag under flags so `grep -E  lm /proc/cpuinfo` should have no output on a 32 bit system, and spit out everything under 'flags' including an entry that says `lm`

The one on my VPS looks like this , and they're running a 64 bit xeon core.

```
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm
```

If you find that either tool tells you its 64 bit capable chances are you can run a 64 bit os, assuming you meet the other system requirements. Otherwise you will have to go for 32 bit.

Comment: Journeyman: they have 2GB of RAM